# Can I make a local stylesheet that essentially removes all CSS from pages I visit?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I want to semi-permanently (temporarily but it lasts past a refresh or following a link) browse without CSS in IE6. There doesn't appear to be a way to permanently disable CSS without messing with the registry.

Can I make a local stylesheet that sets all styles to none, for example, and effectively "turns off" CSS while I browse? What would I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/80.htm

Looks like at least 3 options (thought it would be easier!):

- registry hack
- Accessibility options dialog, though it doesn't completely remove it
- View->Source, edit html and redisplay locally.

Quoting from the page, since it seems to be the most robust solution:

> ...the ability to disable style sheets was removed from internet properties...To work 
>   around this issue, use Registry Editor to open the following registry key...
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\internet Explorer\Main
>
> To disable the use of style sheets, add a string value to the above registry key called > "Use StyleSheets" and set it to no.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options (*that i am aware of*)

1. http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/bookmarklet-to-inject-yahoo-reset-css-into-any-page/
2. Install IE developer toolbar
3. Use firefox which support this natively (and without css it renders the same in all browsers..)

3 is the only one that will persist after reloads..